# How do you call an index in .each_with_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, parameters

Not sure this isn't working.

```
>> params[:payments]
{"0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"80.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/27/2008"}, "1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"5/8/2008"}}
```

So I can call a specific object with this :

```
>> params[:payments][:"1"]
  {":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"5/8/2008"}
```

But if I write this..

```
>> params[:payments].each_with_index{|item, idx| item[:"#{idx}"]}
TypeError Exception: Symbol as array index
```

Idealistically, I want to accomplish this :

```
params[:payments].each_with_index do |item, idx|      
  @calc.payments[idx][:date_paid] = item[:"#{idx}"][":amount_paid"]
  @calc.payments[idx][:amount_paid] = (item[:"#{idx}"][":amount_paid"]).to_f
end
```

**Update:**

Based on some answers, I'ved tried this :

```
params[:payments].each{|k,v| @calc.payments[k.to_i] = v[":amounts_paid"]}
```

This turns `@calc.payments` into :

```
nil
nil
```

Backing up though, the others seem to work..

```
>> params[:payments].each{|k,v| p v[":amount_paid"]}
"80.00"
"100.00"
```

And this one..

```
>> params[:payments].each{|k,v| p @calc.payments[k.to_i]}
{:date_awarded=>"1/2/2008", :judgement_balance=>1955.96}
nil
```

How can I access `item[idx]` in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params[:payments].each do |k,v|
  puts "Item %d amount=%s date=%s\n" % [k, v[":amount_paid"], v[":date_paid"]]
end
Item 0 amount=80.00 date=2/27/2008
Item 1 amount=100.00 date=5/8/2008
```

*Update:*

Ok, ok, here is a complete program .. script .. that you can actually run. *Since you are trying to make sense of Ruby I think you should work with it outside of Rails for a few minutes*. I mocked up `@calc.payments`, whatever that is. This code will run and apparently do what you want.

```
require 'pp'
(params = {})[:payments] = {"0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"80.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/27/2008"}, "1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"5/8/2008"}}
pp params
class T; attr_accessor :payments; end
(@calc = T.new).payments = []
params[:payments].each do |k,v|
  i = k.to_i
  @calc.payments[i] ||= {}
  @calc.payments[i][:date_paid]   = v[":date_paid"]
  @calc.payments[i][:amount_paid] = v[":date_paid"].to_f
end
pp @calc.payments
```

If you run it you should see:

```
{:payments=>
  {"0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"80.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/27/2008"},
   "1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"5/8/2008"}}}
[{:date_paid=>"2/27/2008", :amount_paid=>2.0},
 {:date_paid=>"5/8/2008", :amount_paid=>5.0}]
```

Comment: I wonder if its possible to use that variable injection you used to write the params I'm working on above. Is that SQL? Never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a this to access the values. Since `params[:payments]` contains a hash, then for each pass through, `key`, will be assigned the "0", "1", etc., and `value` will be assigned the hash with `amount_paid` and `date_paid`.

```
params[:payments].each do |key, value|
  amount_paid = value[":amount_paid"]
  ...
end
```

Comment: The first line in your updated code may need a `.to_f` on the end of `v[":amounts_paid"]`